# C5.0 models require a factor outcome

Tags: r

I am working with the credit.csv for building a learning tree, the data is available in:

https://github.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/blob/master/credit.csv

and I have made the following steps:

```
credit<-read.csv("credit.csv")
set.seed(12345)
credit_rand<-credit[order(runif(1000)),]
credit_train<-credit_rand[1:900,]
credit_test<-credit_rand[901:1000,]
library(C50)
credit_model<-C5.0(credit_train[-21],credit_train$default)
```

In the guide that I am following it appears that I should get rid of the last column which is the value of default, but I got the following error:

```
Error en C5.0.default(credit_train[, -21], credit_train$default) : 
  C5.0 models require a factor outcome
```

I have tried changing the last line to:

```
credit_model<-C5.0(credit_train[,-21],credit_train$default)
```

but with no success at all.

Any help?

Comment: if you change it to `credit_model<-C5.0(credit_train[,-21],as.factor(credit_train$default))` does it work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your problem is that `C5.0 models require a factor outcome`. You have given the outcome as `credit_train$default`, which is a 1/2 outcome, but R has read it as numeric, rather than a factor:

```
str(credit_train$default)
int [1:900] 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
```

The solution then is to convert it to a factor:

```
credit_train$default<-as.factor(credit_train$default)
str(credit_train$default)

Factor w/ 2 levels "1","2": 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 ...
```

And then run your training:

```
 credit_model<-C5.0(credit_train[-21],credit_train$default)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original data [provided by the publisher](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/support/13251), the class variable (default) is stored in column 17, and not in column 21. Unless there have been significant changes in the past few months, there are good chances that your file is not the correct one.

In my file, which I obtained from that site after purchasing the book, the class variable "default" is a factor with two levels ("yes" and "no"), as it should be.

According to the book, correspondingly, the command that should be performed is

```
credit_model <- C5.0(credit_train[-17], credit_train$default)
```

followed by

```
credit_pred <- predict(credit_model, credit_test)
```

Then it works like a charm.

```
# > CrossTable(credit_test$default, credit_pred,
# +            prop.chisq = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.r = FALSE,
# +            dnn = c('actual default', 'predicted default'))
#
#
#   Cell Contents
# |-------------------------|
# |                       N |
# |         N / Table Total |
# |-------------------------|
#
# 
# Total Observations in Table:  100 
#
# 
#               | predicted default 
#actual default |        no |       yes | Row Total | 
#---------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#            no |        57 |        11 |        68 | 
#               |     0.570 |     0.110 |           | 
#---------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#           yes |        16 |        16 |        32 | 
#               |     0.160 |     0.160 |           | 
#---------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
#  Column Total |        73 |        27 |       100 | 
#---------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

Comment: But if you want to work with the data from the website that you posted, hoping that this data makes sense, the workaround or the solution consists simply in converting the class variable (entries of column 21) from a numerical value into a factor, as described by @jeremycg.